# flip bitmap through header modification in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Does the bitmap header contain information about how to display the image. like for example flipX, flipY properties etc ?

According to http://www.fileformat.info/mirror/egff/ch03_03.htm there are more than one type of bitmap's. The bitmap created by C# is it a windows bitmap or something else ?

Comment: It's a Windows bitmap. AFAIK this format doesn't offer any feature to do what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, flipX and flipY properties don't make a lot of sense for a bitmap. Bitmap files are device independent formats that store raster 2D graphics—it contains pixel data. You can display it however you want; why should that information be embedded into the file? None of the file structures you linked to contain such properties.

Use the `Image.RotateFlip` method to change how it is displayed.

Whose implementation of the .NET Framework are you interested in? Microsoft's? It uses a Windows bitmap, defined either through a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure or the extended version, `BITMAPV5HEADER`, all carefully documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183386.aspx).